# Parse json object in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I see a lot of examples for parsing a json object in jquery using `$.parseJSON` and understood them. However I am missing some basics and I am not able to parse the below VALID json.

```
{
   "studentList":
   [
       {
           "id": 2,
           "name": "Alex",
           "opened": true
       },
       {
           "id": 3,
           "name": "Paul",
           "opened": true
       }
 ]
}
```

All the examples I found over the internet has a structure like below

```
[
       {
           "id": 2,
           "name": "Alex",
           "opened": true
       },
       {
           "id": 3,
           "name": "Paul",
           "opened": true
       }
 ]
```

Notice, its not enclosed in `{ "sudentList": }`. Can someone explain the logic to parse such json?

Comment: [It worked for me](http://jsfiddle.net/hwkZ5/1/)

Comment: When you say you are not able to parse it, what happens? Is an error thrown? Is the object's structure incorrect?

Comment: Why do you want to parse this json? seems it is already parsed.

Comment: @NateKibler There is no error. That json structure is my controllers response. When I say alert(data) it prints [object Object], which I think is correct, but When I do $.parseJSON(data), it does nothing.

Comment: @Jai I want to populate a html table with the data json response

Comment: @user3413825 then there is no need to parse that is already parsed and i also want to mention that do not use alerts when working with json data instead you can use `console.log()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The studentList has two arrays inside. So you can parse the values directly or using `$.each`.

```
var a = { "studentList": [ { "id": 2, "name": "Alex", "opened": true }, { "id": 3, "name": "Paul", "opened": true } ] };

//values shoud be Alex and Paul
console.log(a.studentList[0].name)
console.log(a.studentList[1].name)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EYrxJ/

```
var a = { "studentList": [ { "id": 2, "name": "Alex", "opened": true }, { "id": 3, "name": "Paul", "opened": true } ] };

//values shoud be Alex and Paul
$.each(a.studentList, function() {
    console.log(this.name);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EYrxJ/1/

Comment: Can you please tell me how do I fit that in my code below.     function     sendAjax() {
 alert("document ready");
$.ajax({
    url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/verticals/json/list_verticals",
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: "{}",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    mimeType: 'application/json',
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
   //code must go here
    });
        $('#results').html(json);
    },
    error:function(data,status,er) {
        alert("error: "+data+" status: "+status+" er:"+er);
    }
});

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to format the code in my comment

Comment: So to use a value in your success function, you should be able to use the each method as above or specific value like this for example `success: function(data) { alert(data.studentList[0].name); });`

Comment: This is what I do. alert() works fine. And nothing happens after that. 
    success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
            var json = $.parseJSON(data);
            $.each(json.verticalsList, function() {
                console.log(this.name);
                alert(this.name);
          });
            $('#results').html(json);
        }

Comment: You will have to format your response to populate your table as you see fit. The alert is just showing you the value for debugging purposes. Example would be ` $('#results').html(data.studentList[0].name);`

Comment: You don't need to parse it again. Use data in your foreach. Right after the alert use my each example above and change `a` to `data` and studentList to verticalsList or whatever it's supposed to be. Stop trying to parse it again.

Comment: Yes, its working. Thanks a lot. But, is that the only way to do it? I mean, I got a jsonObj from the backend and I am not using a $.parseJSON()??

Comment: You just need to iterate through the object with each and no need to parse, you already told jQuery that it is json. `dataType:'json'`, so if all is good please mark as accepted.